# What's causing a 'java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem' in my Java code for calculating an average?

Tags: java, function

I am new to Java
can't find what the problem in the code.
just learnt about functions in Java and the question now asked to create a function to print the average.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Ex1 {
        // 1. enter 3 numbers and print average
        public static int printAverage(int a, int b, int c) {
            int av = (a + b + c) / 3;
            return av;
        }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = s.nextInt();
        int b = s.nextInt();
        int c = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(printAverage(a, b, c));

    }
 }
```

This is the code,

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:

```
    at Ex1.main(ex1.java:10)
```

`
this the error

I searched about the error
– The Class or Module Is Not Imported
– Using Non-existent Classes
– A Syntax Error Resulting in Exception in Thread “main” java.lang.error: Unresolved Compilation Problem:
– A Typographical Error
these were the possible errors, I can't identify in mine

Comment: What error does the *compiler* give you *before* you try to run the code?

Comment: if you mean by errors before running as the syntax errors, it shows none

Comment: I don't see any obvious compilation errors myself. Try re-compiling or re-building and running it again.

Comment: I tried doing this and creating a new file and running the code in it too but it is not working.

Comment: The files that I have created before are running without any error. So I think the problem is in this code.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted

Comment: Then there was the problem that it is a “non-project file”, but this problem is shown in other files too but they are running.

Comment: What IDE do you use ?

Comment: VS Code. ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I don't see any obvious syntax errors. However, I noticed that you have the class name defined as Ex1 but the file name is ex1.java. In Java, the class name and the file name should match exactly (case-sensitive). Make sure that the file name is Ex1.java to match the class name

Comment: This was the mistake, it worked after changing the file name. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The name of your *class* and the name of the *file* must match case.
*[Lesson: The "Hello World!" Application (The Java™ Tutorials > Getting Started)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html)*.

> *"HelloWorldApp is not the same as helloworldapp"*

So, if you're class is *Ex1*, the file must also be *Ex1*, not *ex1*.

Comment: Not really much point in repeating an existing answer in the same post

Comment: @g00se, very constructive, thanks.